# Ошибка при преобразовании строки в дату. ORA-00917: отсутствует запятая

Tags: php, oracle

Добавляю в таблицу (БД использую ОРАКЛ) данные по форме!
Отправляю по форме данные типа даты.
Как конвертировать строку в дату? Пишет литерал не соответствует формату!

```
private function save_project() { 
$id = $_POST['id_project']; 
$test_name = $_POST['name_project']; 
$emp_id = $_POST['emp_id']; 
$id_type = $_POST['id_type']; 
$time_result = $_POST['time_result']; 
$state = $_POST['state']; 
$date_close = $_POST['date_close'];
$date = "to_date($date_close, 'dd.mm.yyyy')"; 
if($id == '0'){ 
$sql = "INSERT INTO PROJECT (ID, NAME, EMP_ID, ID_TYPE, TIME_RESULT, STATE, DATE_CLOSE) VALUES (SEQ_PROJECT.NEXTVAL, '$test_name', '$emp_id','$id_type', '$time_result', '$state', '$date')";
}
else{ 
$sql = "update PROJECT set NAME = '$test_name', EMP_ID = '$emp_id', ID_TYPE = '$id_type', TIME_RESULT = '$time_result', STATE = '$state', DATE_CLOSE = '$date' where id = $id"; } 
$m = $this->db->Execute($sql); 
if($m !== true){ 
echo $m; return false;
} 
header("Location: project"); }
```

Ошибка выходит такая ORA-00917: отсутствует запятая

Comment: Покажите [минимальный пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) кода и укажите где и когда возникает ошибка.

Comment: $date_close = $_POST['date_close']; $date = "select to_date($date_close, 'dd.mm.yyyy') from Project"; if($id == '0'){ $sql = "INSERT INTO PROJECT (ID, NAME, EMP_ID, ID_TYPE, TIME_RESULT, STATE, DATE_CLOSE) VALUES (SEQ_PROJECT.NEXTVAL, '$test_name', '$emp_id','$id_type',
'$time_result', '$state', '$date')"; }else{ $sql = "update PROJECT set NAME = '$test_name', EMP_ID = '$emp_id', ID_TYPE = '$id_type', TIME_RESULT = '$time_result', STATE = '$state', DATE_CLOSE = '$date' where id = $id"; }

Comment: все данные беру с массива $_POST

Comment: ошибка выходит такая ORA-00917: отсутствует запятая

Comment: Под вопросом есть ссылка «править». Внесите всю нужную информацию в текст.

Comment: Уберите одинаерные кавычки `DATE_CLOSE = $date`. И добавьте их в `$date = "to_date('$date_close', 'dd.mm.yyyy')"; `

Comment: можешь в коде прописать и скинуть, я сделал как ты сказал но не работает, та же самая ошибка!

Comment: Нужно посмотреть каким получился запрос в `$sql` перед выполнением (вывести его в логи или на страницу)  и попробовать прогнать его в Oracle (через sqlplus/SQL Developer неважно). Если после этого будет непонятно, опубликуйте запрос и на какой строке/позиции возникает ошибка.

Comment: Вместо $date = "to_date($date_close, 'dd.mm.yyyy')"; написал это $date = " select to_date('$date_close', 'dd.mm.yyyy') from dual";

Comment: сам запрос прогнал через оракл, вместо переменной поставил лубую дату все норм работает, но когда прогоняю в своем проекте выходить ошибка ORA-00917: отсутствует запятая ! ХЗ не могу понять